# sum (aggregation) one field in document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, sum, backend, aggregation

i'm beginner spring-boot and mongodb developer
i have category and some content in category

```
       [
        
          {
            _id ="5f9d89f5d7bb2c56b678614b",
            categoryId="5f8066dad0b65b3b9ca67e4b",
            likeCount=10
        },
     {
            _id ="5f9d89f5456b2c56b678614b",
            categoryId="5f8066dad0b65b3b9cnhk44",
            likeCount=5
  }
    {
        ]
```

I want to calculate the total likeCount in this document, which is equal to 15 in this example, and display it in the category list.
what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you have nested array you can try like this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$fieldName"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            sum: {
                $sum: "$fieldName.likeCount"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

in other case use just this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            sum: {
                $sum: "$likeCount"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks but how can i use it in spring boot?